# Jenkins Project Based Security

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using role based security in jenkinks.

what i am wondering is there a to do the following.

**Present:**

using role based plugin.

under Manager and assign roles

- "**global roles**" >> where i have an "admin" he can create a project
- " **Project roles**" >> created individual project which lets you build/delete/ect a job - but does not create a job

issue is:

- i want one person to have the admin rights to create a project
- team members to go into that project and create jobs but only for there project they have given the rights to without given them "global admin rights"

**Future what i want:**

**admin Role**:

- to give person admin ( global rights) where he can go create the Application(project).

**project based**:

- the team members to have the rights to create and delete jobs only for there Application (Project).and not have access to another Applicatons(project) and not given global rights to create other projects or to touch other people projects

any new security rights plugin out there, i am using role-based plugin.

any new interesting plugin i can checkout to see which direction i can go?

Comment: You haven't posted anything under the "Present:" label.  Also, you can format code by using four spaces in front of it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

You need this:

```
First step is install the plugin "Jenkins Role Strategy Plugin".
Second step is reset Jenkins.
```

Follow the steps:

1. Login to Jenkins with your credentials.
2. Go to "Manage Jenkins".
3. Go to "Configure Global Security".
4. In the option "Authorization" select "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy" and put the privileges as appropriate.

Obviously, if you need have permissions like  administrator, then will put the privileges as appropriate.

Note:
If you need put privileges by job, then  will must  setting for each job in the option "Enable project-based security".

Regards...

Answer (score 2):

@adam,

Take a look at [Jenkins Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin).

> This plugin adds a new role-based strategy to ease and fasten users
>   management. This strategy allows:
>
> - Creating global roles, such as admin, job creator, anonymous, etc.,
>     allowing to set Overall, Slave, Job, Run, View and SCM permissions on
>     a global basis.
> - Creating project roles, allowing to set only Job and
>     Run permissions on a project basis.
> - Creating slave roles, allowing to
>     set node-related permissions.
> - Assigning these roles to users.

Hope that helps.